# Numerically solving differential equations for multiple initial conditions with Maple

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, vector-analysis, 3d, maple

I need to draw a dozen of field lines using *Maple*, by solving three differential equations.  Here's a fully working code for *Maple*, to be modified :

```
restart:
with(linalg):
with(DEtools):

Position := [x(t), y(t), z(t)]:
r := sqrt(x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 + z(t)^2):

Mu := [0, 0, 1]:
DipolarField := 3*innerprod(Mu, Position)*Position - Mu*r^2:

Bx := innerprod([1, 0, 0], DipolarField):
By := innerprod([0, 1, 0], DipolarField):
Bz := innerprod([0, 0, 1], DipolarField):

s1 := -50:
s2 := 50:

eq1 := (D(x))(t) = Bx:
eq2 := (D(y))(t) = By:
eq3 := (D(z))(t) = Bz:

x0 := 1.0:
y0 := 0.0:
z0 := 0.0:

InitConditions := x(0) = x0, y(0) = y0, z(0) = z0:
FieldLines := dsolve({eq1, eq2, eq3, InitConditions}, {x(t), y(t), z(t)}, numeric, range = s1..s2, maxfun=0):

plots[odeplot](FieldLines, [x(t), y(t), z(t)], s1..s2, numpoints = 1000, axes = boxed, scaling = constrained, thickness = [3], color = ["Green"]);
```

This code draws a nice lonely field line.  But then I need that code to simultaneously draw 12 field lines, all starting on the equatorial circle, and show them all in the plot.  I thus need to change the initial conditions **x0** and **y0** to something like **cos(theta)** and **sin(theta)**, and tell *Maple* to do the numerical integration for **theta = 0, Pi/12, 2Pi/12, 3Pi/12, 4Pi/12, ..., 11Pi/12**, but I don't know how.

I'm not an experienced user of *Maple* (I usually use *Mathematica*), so I dont know how to do this with *Maple*.  Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just have to stick it in a MAPLE do loop, something like:

```
restart:
with(linalg):
with(DEtools):

Position := [x(t), y(t), z(t)]:
r := sqrt(x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 + z(t)^2):

Mu := [0, 0, 1]:
DipolarField := 3*innerprod(Mu, Position)*Position - Mu*r^2:

Bx := innerprod([1, 0, 0], DipolarField):
By := innerprod([0, 1, 0], DipolarField):
Bz := innerprod([0, 0, 1], DipolarField):

s1 := -50:
s2 := 50:

eq1 := (D(x))(t) = Bx:
eq2 := (D(y))(t) = By:
eq3 := (D(z))(t) = Bz:

theta_list:= [seq(i*Pi/12, i=0..11)]: # YOUR THETA VALUES

COLOUR_LIST:= [blue, black, red, green, yellow, cyan, gold, gray, orange, brown, pink, magenta]: 
# LIST OF COLOURS - CAN BE ANYTHING AS LONG AS YOU HAVE 12 DIFFERENT ONES!

for j from 1 to nops(theta_list) do # THE MAGIC 'DO' LOOP

    theta_val:= theta_list[j]: # VALUE OF THETA FOR EACH j IN LOOP

    COL:= COLOUR_LIST[j]: # ASSIGNS A DIFFERENT COLOUR FOR EACH j IN LOOP

    x0 := cos(theta_val):
    y0 := sin(theta_val):
    z0 := 0.0:

    InitConditions := x(0) = x0, y(0) = y0, z(0) = z0:
    FieldLines := dsolve({eq1, eq2, eq3, InitConditions}, {x(t), y(t), z(t)}, numeric, range = s1..s2, maxfun=0):

    PLT[j]:= plots[odeplot](FieldLines, [x(t), y(t), z(t)], s1..s2, numpoints = 1000, axes = boxed, scaling = constrained, thickness = [3], color = COL); 
    # ASSIGNS A NAME FOR EACH PLOT FOR EACH THETA VALUE 
    # NOTE EACH PLOT IS A DIFFERENT COLOUR DUE TO "color=COL"

od: # END OF j LOOP

plots[display]( seq(PLT[k], k=1..nops(theta_list)) ); 
# DISPLAYS ALL PLOTS FOR ALL THETA VALUES TOGETHER, EACH A DIFFERENT COLOUR
```

I have tried to annotate the changes. I also added different colours for each plot so that hopefully you can distinguish each curve. If you don't want that, just delete this list and change the color back to color=["Green"] in odeplot. I haven't debugged it as I don't have MAPLE on the machine I am currently using, but hope this helps!

Comment: This is working great.  However, I'm wondering if there's another way, simpler, in doing this.  The "do" loop feels different to what I would have done using *Mathematica*.

Comment: Is there a way to add a simple 3D sphere (or a generic ball) in the middle of the graph ?  Is there a ball primitive in *Maple* ?

Comment: Maple does have a simple sphere command within the plottools library. One thing I do like about Maple is it tends to have a good and useful help facility: just write ?sphere into Maple and all the information you need should be there. Just assign the plot a name and add it to the list in plots[display] outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks !  The sphere looks great.